# EC2に置いてあるダンプファイルをRDS(MySQL)にインポートしたい

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

EC2内で、ダンプファイルのあるディレクトリで下記コマンドを実行するとエラーが表示されます。
セキュリティグループは統一してあるのですが、何か設定が必要ですか？

```
mysql -h abc.c3uoslncvvzp.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com < schema.sql

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'1××.××.11.22' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -p -h mysql -h abc.c3uoslncvvzp.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com [テーブル名] < schema.sql
```

で解決しました。